# trigger an alert after slide change with malsup Cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm using Malsup's jQuery Cycle plugin and have the following code that runs it nicely and also adds the class .current to the slide that is active.

```
$('#banner') 
    .cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed: '1000', 
    timeout: '8000', 
    pager: '#pager',
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    cleartypeNoBg: 'true',
    before: function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.current').removeClass();
    },
    after: function(){
       $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Now what i wanted to do (for the sake of testing codes) is trigger an alert when the .current class changes slide. I have tried:

```
$('#banner').find('.current').change(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

But it didnt work at all, what is it that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.change()` only works on `inputs` or `contenteditable`. There is no event triggered when the class changes. You have to create your own.

```
$('#banner') 
    .cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed: '1000', 
    timeout: '8000', 
    pager: '#pager',
    next: '#next',
    prev: '#prev',
    cleartypeNoBg: 'true',
    before: function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.current').removeClass();
    },
    after: function(){
       $(this).addClass('current').trigger('changeClass');
    }
});
```

And then you do

```
$('#banner').on('changeClass', function(){
   alert($(this).find('.current').index());
})
```

Comment: haha i forgot to wrap it in a doc ready, perfect solution thanks!